# how to check if file already exists in qt simple mediaplayer

Tags: c++, qt, openfiledialog

i have a simple media player and one of the features is that the player has a list of the videos that are opened , i want to create an additional feature where it checks wether the video or "file" has already been opened and stop it from opening i have tried something like this but it didnt work :

```
bool fileExists(QString path)= QFileInfo::exists(path).isFile();
if (fileExists(path)== true)
{ 
   qDebug() <<"file already exists";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this here makes no sense:

```
bool fileExists(QString path)= QFileInfo::exists(path).isFile();
```

---

my suggestion to you is to define a method instead:

```
bool MainWindow::fileExists(QString path)
{
    QFileInfo fi(path);
    return fi.exists(path) && fi.isFile();
}
```

and for using it:

```
QString path{"/myPathToFile/myVideo.mp4"};

if (fileExists(path))
{
   qDebug() << "file already exists";
}
```